# how to collect data in list from alerts with flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, collections, addition

I'm trying to collect data in list from alertDialogs.
In every alert there's some data that I have to retrive it. I have to retrive the data from each alert and then put all the data that is retrived from all the alertDialogs in one list.
For now, I arrived juste to retrive the data of every alert but I don't know how to save all the data on one list.
this is my code:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                    List list1 = [
                      data.x,
                      data.y,
                     
                    ];

                    List list2 = [];

                    list2.add(list1);
                  
                  });
```

```
return AlertDialog(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    content: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  '${data.x}\n',
```

Comment: Can you post your AlertDialog code?

Comment: @rrttrr I added a part of the alert